# List of CDN URL's used for Winget

Tags: windows, powershell, intune, winget

I am currently trying to roll Microsoft Store app (new) via Intune, but it looks like some of the CDN URLs are being blocked by our web filtering software (Forcepoint)

I would like to know where winget pulls the installers from so that I can look at getting exceptions put in place.

This is an example of where Winget reaches out to for [Adobe Creative Cloud](https://ffc-static-cdn.oobesaas.adobe.com:443/wam/2.10.0.17/win/Creative_Cloud_Set-Up.exe)

I know that Microsoft Apps use the standard [Microsoft store URL](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail), but I am just curious to see if there is a list for 3rd party applications?

Answer (score 2):

3rd party software is submitted to winget through this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs) if you're using the default sources.

All of the installer data, such as URLs, can be found in [manifest files](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/tree/master/manifests). You can extract `Installers` -> `InstallerUrl` field from the `.installer.yaml` files, like [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/blob/master/manifests/a/Adobe/Acrobat/Reader/64-bit/23.001.20064/Adobe.Acrobat.Reader.64-bit.installer.yaml).